# Rで{e1071}パッケージを用いるとpredictで(subscript) 論理値添え字が長すぎますというエラーが出る件

Tags: r

表題の件で、ご質問させてください。
コードは下記の要領です。
いつもpredictの箇所でエラーになります。
どうしたらよいか、ご教授願います。

install.packages("e1071")
library(e1071)

data.train <-read.csv("predict_shop4_7_1.csv",header=T)
head(data.train)
data.test <-read.csv("predict_shop4_3_1.csv",header=T)
head(data.test)

dim(data.train)
[1] 700   8

dim(data.test)
[1] 300   8

table(data.train[,8])
table(data.test[,8])

d.svm <- svm(status~.,data.train)
print(d.svm)

d.test.svm.pred <- predict(d.svm,data.test)

> d.test.svm.pred <- predict(d.svm,data.test)
>    以下にエラー newdata[, object$scaled, drop = FALSE] : 
>      (subscript) 論理値添え字が長すぎます

summary(d.test.svm.pred)

Comment: [Getting an error "(subscript) logical subscript too long" while training SVM from e1071 package in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109219/getting-an-error-subscript-logical-subscript-too-long-while-training-svm-fro)